# I accidentaly gave /etc 777 permission with chmod

Tags: sudo, archlinux, chmod

i recently installed arch linux on a virtual drive for fun and to learn programming.I wanted to install a different envirement for arch and i found this website:
https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@farahnabilla/how-to-install-desktop-environment-on-arch-linux
When i got to the lightdm --test-mode --debug it said i didnt have permission.So I decided that i would use chmod on /etc, I gave it 777 permission (BIG NO NO !!!!) and now every time i use sudo it gives me this error:
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit

i figured i could try installing sudo again via pacman but it says i dont have permisson but i cant use sudo because of the previous error. there must be a way to re download sudo without using sudo in terminal.
please help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can install `sudo` from `root` user(as this user have privileges for EVERYTHING)

To login into root user use the following command:

```sh
su root
```

and type the root password

Or you can just change all permissions from this user

Comment: Would booting from a CD and mounting the disk allow them to fix the permissions?

Comment: Yes, you can fix the problem in such way

Comment: **Or you can just change all permissions from this user**  Directories are 755, files are 644